# Joomla! 1.5.26 TinyMCE init from JEditor or Javascript

Tags: jquery, joomla, tinymce

Basically, the Joomla! editor (JCE/TinyMCE) based on a parameter can be enabled or disabled when the users load the specific page. 
Disabled means: the content is not editable and the opacity background must be set.

In the default.php:

```
<?php
    $editor =& JFactory::getEditor();
    /*
    Parameter Type Default  Description
    $name string The control name
    $html string The contents of the text area
    $width string The width of the text area (px or %)
    $height string The height of the text area (px or %)
    $col int The number of columns for the textarea
    $row int The number of rows for the textarea
    $buttons boolean    true    True and the editor buttons will be displayed
    $params array array()   Associative array of editor parameters
    */
    echo $editor->display('emailText', $this->articleFullText, '960', '700', '20', '20', false);
?>
```

Is it possible to set the editor settings in the default.php (view)? 
(I did not find any specific parameter)

I created the following function (thanks to stackoverflow) which enables or disables the editor

```
function setEditorEditable(editable) {
    if (editable == 1) {
        tinymce.get(tinymce.activeEditor.id).getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true');
        J('#' + tinymce.activeEditor.id + '_parent').fadeTo(0, 1);
    } else {
        tinymce.get(tinymce.activeEditor.id).getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', 'false');
        J('#' + tinymce.activeEditor.id + '_parent').fadeTo(0, 0.5);
    }
}
```

But, if I call the function within the jQuery .ready the editor DOM obj is null.

How and where in code can I set/change the editor setting?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on which editor setting you want to change and the point of time.
It is possible to set some parameters onInit of the editor. Some other parameters cannot be changed afterwards.

Comment: Basically, reading the doc [link](http://docs.joomla.org/JEditor/1.5) (very poor) it's not possible to set the JCE CSS based on a custom PHP parameter set in the view.html.php of my component. I decided to do it at the jQuery level, but of course the jEditor obj in the DOM is not defined yet in the jQuery .ready(). Mission impossible?

Comment: so, you basically want to add a custom stylesheet to the editor?

Comment: It could be a workaround. In the default.php (Joomla! HTML template of the MVC pattern) I could set the theme disabled (but I don't know how I can set the editor editable param to false and how can I load a different CSS for the editor at the PHP level (echo $editor->display('emailText', $this->articleFullText, '960', '700', '20', '20', false);)...anyway). 
Briefly, based on a PHP variable got from the model, I load the disabled editor else I load the default editor...

Comment: you do not have a javascript option at all?

Comment: do you have access to the tinymce initialization?

Comment: No, basically the editor is loaded following this rule [link](http://docs.joomla.org/JFactory/getEditor) or [link1](http://docs.joomla.org/JEditor/1.5) and I cannot change the Joomla! core files...and to extend the JEditor class for this "simple" issue  it's a big Scheiße!

Comment: "Scheiße" - wow, what a great german word :)   if possible never touch core files, but i guess there should be a way to configure the joomla editor (in most CMS there is a way to influence the configuration - is there a configuration file which you may edit someplace? )

Comment: have a look here: http://joomla.boastworthy.com/how-to/21-configure-the-tinymce-editor-in-joomla.pdf  and take a closer look at the custom_css setting

Comment: I think I have almost read everything on the Internet (that doc too). I can say I cannot change on-the-fly the JEditor options before page has finished to load without touching the JCE component core files....My solution will be: when the user tries to edit the content (in the DOM the editor obj is loaded) I call the setEditorEditable function. Really, thanks thanks thanks a lot for supporting me!